# pandas simpleimputer preserve datatypes

Tags: pandas

I am facing a simple error with the code below.

My objective is to use simpleimputer to plug missing values of different datatypes in one shot.

When i try to do that, the fit_transform seems to be not work as expected.
When dtype argument is not used, the code works just fine, but the resulting dataframe loses its data type information. When i include the dtype list in the arguments, i am seeing the below error. You should be able to simulate the error by just copying and pasting in your local.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

import sklearn
print(sklearn.__version__)

0.21.dev0

data = [['Alex','NJ',21,5.10],['Mary','NY',20,np.nan],['Sam',np.nan,np.nan,6.3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','State','Age','Height'])

df.dtypes
Name       object
State      object
Age       float64
Height    float64
dtype: object                 

imp = SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent")

#df = pd.DataFrame(imp.fit_transform(df),columns=df.columns)   <<<<----- This works just fine
#df
#Name   State   Age Height
#0  Alex    NJ  21  5.1
#1  Mary    NY  20  5.1
#2  Sam NJ  20  6.3
#df.dtypes
#Name      object
#State     object
#Age       object
#Height    object
#dtype: object
```

The below statement fails - with the error listed below ( I am trying to preserve dtypes during imputing process)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(imp.fit_transform(df),columns=df.columns,dtype=df.dtypes)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-e9780979921f> in <module>()
      7 
      8 imp = SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent")
----> 9 df = pd.DataFrame(imp.fit_transform(df),columns=df.columns,dtype=df.dtypes)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    337             data = {}
    338         if dtype is not None:
--> 339             dtype = self._validate_dtype(dtype)
    340 
    341         if isinstance(data, DataFrame):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _validate_dtype(self, dtype)
    166 
    167         if dtype is not None:
--> 168             dtype = pandas_dtype(dtype)
    169 
    170             # a compound dtype

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\common.py in pandas_dtype(dtype)
   2020     # which we safeguard against by catching them earlier and returning
   2021     # np.dtype(valid_dtype) before this condition is evaluated.
-> 2022     if dtype in [object, np.object_, 'object', 'O']:
   2023         return npdtype
   2024     elif npdtype.kind == 'O':

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1574         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
   1575                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
-> 1576                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
   1577 
   1578     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to preserve the dtype, I recommend using pandas to find the mode and then call `fillna`:

```
df = df.fillna(df.agg(lambda x: pd.Series.mode(x)[0], axis=0))
print(df)
   Name State   Age  Height
0  Alex    NJ  21.0     5.1
1  Mary    NY  20.0     5.1
2   Sam    NJ  20.0     6.3

print(df.dtypes)
Name       object
State      object
Age       float64
Height    float64
dtype: object
```

---

Alternatively, use `astype` and pass a dictionary:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
     imp.fit_transform(df), columns=df.columns
).astype(df.dtypes.to_dict())

print(df)
   Name State   Age  Height
0  Alex    NJ  21.0     5.1
1  Mary    NY  20.0     5.1
2   Sam    NJ  20.0     6.3

print(df.dtypes)
Name       object
State      object
Age       float64
Height    float64
dtype: object
```

Explicit `astype` call is needed because, as per the documentation, only a single `dtype` can be passed to the `pd.DataFrame` constructor.

> ```
> ?pd.DataFrame
> ...
> dtype : dtype, default None
>  |      Data type to force. Only a single dtype is allowed.
> ```

Comment: Added version info to the original question. I want to use the imputer function which is much more readable and has the ability to take in dtypes parameter.